# Trying to show all permutations possible without recursion

Tags: java

I'm trying to show all combinations possible without using recursion.
I was trying it with a loop but it isn't working.

Without recursion(Not Working):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Combination {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arr = {"A","B","C","D","E","F"};
        String[] result = new String[3];
        int i = 0, len = 3;
        while(len != 0 || i <= arr.length-len) 
        {
            result[result.length - len] = arr[i];
            len--;
            i++;          
        }

        if (len == 0){
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
            return;
        }
    }    
}
```

With recursion(Working):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Combination {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String[] arr = {"A","B","C","D","E","F"};
        combinations2(arr, 3, 0, new String[3]);
    }

    static void combinations2(String[] arr, int len, int startPosition, String[] result){
        if (len == 0){
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
            return;
        }       
        for (int i = startPosition; i <= arr.length-len; i++){
            result[result.length - len] = arr[i];
            combinations2(arr, len-1, i+1, result);
        }
    }       
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It isn't outputting the combinations.

Comment: What's the expected outcome on a smaller set? so for example: with the set {"A", "B"} would u get "A", "B", "AB", "BA"? or what exactly?

Comment: @Thresh yes thats what you should get.

Comment: @MikeB You need to get all permutations not combinations. You need a function like next_permutation in c++

Comment: @Thresh Oops, I read the question but not the comments. Seems odd to ask for combinations when what you really want is permutations.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what is the answer you are trying to get. The question should be set with example data to specify exactly what is it that you want to get. Given the part of the program you provided. I guess what you are looking for is all possible subsets.

the following code will get you all the possible subsets. You can easily modify this program to give you all possible subsets of a specific size (Try it to make sure you understand how it works).

```
static void subsets(String[]arr) {
    int len = arr.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < (1 << len); i++) { // 1 << len means 2 ^ len there are 2 ^ n subsets for a set of size n
        /* 
         * We will use the bits of the integer i to represent which elements are taken
         * a bit of value 1 means this element is included in the current subset
         * a bit of value 0 means that we do not take the element in the given position
         */
        String res = "[";
        for(int j = 0; j < len; j++) { //loop over the bits of i from 0 to len -1
            if ( (i & (1 << j)) != 0) { 
                //the jth bit is 1 in the integer i as such the jth 
                //element is taken in the current subset
                res += (arr[j]+", ");   
            }
        }
        res += "]";
        int lastCommaPosition = res.lastIndexOf(',');
        if (res.lastIndexOf(',') != -1) { // a comma exists
            res = res.substring(0, lastCommaPosition)+ "]";//remove the extra comma and space
        }
        System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```

You can modify the method above to take an integer size for example, count the number of bits of value 1 (the number of elements taken) if this count is equal to the size you print it otherwise you don't. Feel free to modify the question if this is not the answer you wanted or ask in the comments if there is something you don't understand.

Comment: Thanks! It is really useful =)

Answer (score -1):

Here is how you can get the exact output without recursion. I am using for loops though:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length - 2; i ++) {
        for(int j = i + 1; j < arr.length - 1; j++ ) {
            for(int k = j + 1; k < arr.length ; k++ ) {
                System.out.println(arr[i] + ", " + arr[j] + ", " + arr[k]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Actually that doesn't get all the permutations.

Comment: What do you mean? I got 20 combinations from your recursive method and 20 from my method. Which one do you think is missing?

Comment: Try it on 7 elements won't get all combinations you need to list them on your own notice you need all permutations. So order matters AB would be different from BA

Comment: Yes, tried on 7 elements and got 35 combinations from both. You need to actually run the program and find out what you get. Anyway.

Comment: The OP asked for combinations but what he really wanted was permutations. He clarified in the comments but didn't bother to update the question.